# Keyboard not working after suspend Ubuntu 20.04 Lenovo IdeaPad L340

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

I tried the fixes available on the internet, of which I found two, but none of them worked.
1st: changing the /etc/default/grub, where GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" changes to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset" and then **update-grub**, then **reboot**
2nd:**sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all**

Neither of the two worked, and I would really appreciate being able to use my keyboard, as much as I would appreciate some suggestions as to how to fix this issue. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Tried this as well, didn't work.
sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf ------- where I wrote in

## bug in module breaks keyboard, so don't load it

blacklist intel_vbtn

Even after blacklisting intel_vbtn, the command cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type gives me 10, and supposedly it should be either **31** or **32**

PS: I forgot to mention one detail, the **power** button is the only one that works. Peculiar, do you not think so?

**Thanks to everybody who at least thought about trying to answer this question. It suddenly started working today by itself. The only *problem that I have now is that it keeps turning my microphone on and off when I press some keys on the keyboard.* I don't suppose anybody here can figure this one out as well, but I'll mention it just in case.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try the i8042.reset option ( frequent on clevo models ) to add in the /etc/default/grub :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset"
```

And run

```
sudo update-grub
```

after and reboot

Comment: Thank you kindly for the suggestion, but it did not work.

Comment: This worked in 2023 on my Lenovo Yoga Thinkpad X1 gen4 running Ubuntu 22.04 5.15.0.91-generic. Where could I read more about it though? I am curious about potential side-effects. I found some (tiny) docs [in the kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt)

Answer (score 0):

TL;RD: `i8042.noaux`

I had this problem and found solution here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2241355&sid=d2cf96c073389693f62bbc4d89c5fec3#p2241355
It is similar to solution of Michel, but the option is `i8042.noaux` - it is noticed there:

> "... A firmware or kernel bug causes ACPI PNP devices to appear as available, which in turn causes the i8042 module to detect AUX ports, which are probed during resume, and this causes the keyboard to cease functioning. A workaround is to add i8042.noaux to the kernel command line..."

So, adding `i8042.noaux` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` in `/etc/default/grub` to be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.noaux"` (in my case) with `sudo update-grub && sudo reboot` fixes the problem.